# Program which decides if there are two integers a and b in a given array such that a + b = c

Tags: python, arrays, mergesort

I need to write a program which decides if there are two integers `a` and `b` in a given list such that `a + b = c`. The input would be a list and the integer `c`. It could be the case, that `a == b`, but `a` must appear two times in the list in that case. The run time must be in `O(n*log(n))`.

I have tried to implement a binary search, but since the list must be sorted for that, it is not going to work if the list is not sorted because the sorting would take at least `O(n*log(n))` time. I am trying to implement merge sort without merging at the end, and just getting `a` and `b`, but I don't know if it is a dead end. What would be your way to even get started? It's really important that run time is not above `O(n*log(n))`.

Comment: Why not just sort?

Comment: (There are also hash-based options that run in "hopefully O(n)", but why not just sort?)

Comment: Hard to give feeback on code you don't share.  Include it in text form, along with any relevant input and output .

Comment: sorting is n*log(n), whatever after would be O(n) at most, so just sort.

Comment: @RockyLi. The portion after would also be O(nlog(n)), not O(n)

Comment: Are you allowed to use extra memory?  A solution where you keep a set of seen numbers, and for every number `x` you encounter lookup `c-x` in the set would be `O(n)`

Comment: Is this homework or an interview question?

Comment: Once the array is sorted, you can find the two numbers in O(n) - start with a pointer to each end of the array, then repeatedly increment the low pointer if the sum is too low, or decrement the high pointer if the sum is too high.  Either you find a match, or the pointers collide after `n` steps.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Why? Use two pointer from opposite side and you traverse the sorted list exactly once.

Comment: @RockyLi. Good call. I hadn't considered that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting in-place can be done in `O(n log(n))` time. The subsequent search can also be done in `O(n)` time, resulting in a total of `O(n log(n))`. Once the data is sorted, for each element `a` of the array, check if `c - a` is also in the array using a simultaneous search from the other end. You will traverse the entire array exactly once that way. This approach is suggested by [@RockyLi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53840158/2988730?noredirect=1#comment94528913_53840158). It has the advantage of using `O(1)` *additional* memory: the input list needs to be sorted in-place.

If using `O(n)` *additional* memory is acceptable, you can follow [@PatrickHaugh's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53840158/2988730?noredirect=1#comment94528730_53840158). Create a set. Add every element, `a`, in the list to the set. If `c - a` is already in the set, return `True`. This requires `O(n)` time to complete (a single pass), and no sorting. But it will likely more than double the amount of memory you use.

Here are toy implementations:

**O(1) space, O(n log(n)) time**

```
def has_sum(lst, c):
    lst.sort()
    rev = reversed(lst)
    end = next(rev)
    for item in lst:
        while end > c - item:
            end = next(rev)
        if end == c - item:
            return True
        if item > end:
            return False
```

**O(n) space, O(n) time**

```
def has_sum(lst, c):
    found = set()
    for item in lst:
        if c - item in found:
            return True
        found.add(item)
    return False
```

Comment: thank you very much, using additional memmory is acceptable. i have tried this input with the first function: has_sum([17, 20, 26, 31, 44, 54, 55, 77, 93],75) but it returns False. The second function returns True though

Comment: @sacchh. Fixed. I was checking `end == item` instead of `end == c - item`